# What can I replace copper with for my salt water battery?

Tags: batteries, water, power-generation, corrosion

I and my friends were trying to make a salt water battery, but we cannot find copper strips in our town. Is there any other electrode we can use to make our battery? We have aluminum foil (which is one of our electrodes); what else should we use?

Comment: graphite would do.

Comment: Thx but can you give me a easily available electrode

Comment: @KartikPillai: we have no idea what is easily available at your place. You migh want to ask what of your materials is a good idea, also thats more a chemistry/Physics than an EE question.

Comment: Almost any other (not aluminium) conductive material will do but the voltage you get will depend on the material. Aluminium probably does not work for a battery anyway as it forms an oxide layer on its surface. You can scrape that off but it will form immediately again. Zink, copper, lead etc are better choices.

Comment: What town? | Al - air works but lectrode surface must be abraded regularly. Zonc air has less problems. Rather than using salt water, mild alkaline electrolyte may give substantially higher voltage. Burning hardwood (especially) to charcoal and running water through the ashes gives you an Alkaline solution suitable as battery electrolyte.| The carbon can be used as an electrode.

Comment: One possible source of copper that you might not have thought of is the bigger hobby stores like Michaels.

Comment: Don't you have copper wire?

Comment: Ya plenty of them (copper wire)

Comment: A few moments work with a big hammer and you could turn ordinary copper plumbing pipe into a copper strip.

Comment: My first thought also is copper pipe. Also useful for an impromptu guitar slide.

Answer (score 8):

What you need to look for is two metals with a large ["Galvanic Potential"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_corrosion#Galvanic_series) between them. This is also known as a metals Anodic Index. Copper and Zinc is just one of many options.

The following is a partial chart of Anodic Indices of various materials:

[image: Anodic Index]
<sup>Image source [here](http://premierrv.net/galvanic-corrosion.html).</sup>

As you can see, Copper is quite Cathodic at \$-0.35\mathrm{V}\$, while Zinc is quite Anodic at \$-1.25\mathrm{V}\$. You would expect a terminal voltage of about:

$$V=V_{Cu}-V_{Zn}=(-0.35)-(-1.25)=0.9\mathrm{V}$$

To replace Copper and get a similar voltage, you could use something like Nickel which is similar to copper at \$-0.3\mathrm{V}\$. Gunmetal (Red Brass) would also work, giving a similar potential to copper. Alternatively you could use something like Graphite - like from a pencil - which is at \$0.3\mathrm{V}\$, so would actually give you a much higher voltage.

Basically pick two materials, one which is Cathodic, and one which is Anodic.

Comment: Do bog-standard dry cells still have a tube of graphite down the middle? There's a handy cathode.

Comment: @user65586 -- Yes. Ray-O-Vac lantern 6v dry cells have four long cells with correspondingly long graphite anodes that can be easily extracted.

Comment: My local Walmarts all have cheap (<= $6 USD last time I looked) Rayovac flashlights that come with one of these dry cell lantern batteries. (Good Joule Thief project boxes!)   I've also seen these graphite rods used for making an arc-furnace for melting copper at "King of Random".

Answer (score 2):

Try Stainless steel crubbers, while stainless steel is an alloy of iron/nickel and chrome, but it's standard reduction potential is the same or even more positive the Copper and the scrubbers have a large surface area

Answer (score 1):

If you really want copper, try looking in a home improvement store for roof flashing.  This is often available in copper and aluminum.

However, there are a number of other materials that will work.  There must be a chart somewhere that gives the electrochemical potential of various materials.  For example, early commercial batteries were made with carbon and zinc electrodes.

Comment: Thx i will check my nearest home improvement store soon

Comment: Or even copper tubing or fittings.

Comment: @KartikPillai - You might also try looking for brass. Brass is a copper-zinc alloy and should work OK. It will cost more, though.